# Date casting in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How does following query work , could not find documents explaining how following query works.Are there any other similar queries for casting values?

SELECT date '2017-01-01' FROM dual;

> Gives result 1/1/2017

Comment: Is there any documentation of this type of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is using a date literal.  From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

> You can specify a DATE value as a string literal, or you can convert a character or numeric value to a date value with the TO_DATE function. DATE literals are the only case in which Oracle Database accepts a TO_DATE expression in place of a string literal.
>
> To specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:

```
DATE '1998-12-25'
```

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks!